# How do I use an if statement inside the where clause in this sql statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

```
 select * 
 from mytable
 where (if @key=0 
           pkey>=0
        else
           pkey = @key)
```

`@key` is the value passed in to the stored procedure and `pkey` is a column in `mytable`.

Comment: fwiw, you'd do better passing NULL for @key instead of 0. That might allow you to simplify the code somewhat if all your pkeys are > 0: `WHERE coalesce(@key, pkey) = pkey`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `CASE` (*bit like the way you are trying with `if`*) as below. ([DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8deea/21))

```
select * 
from mytable
where pkey = case when @key <> 0 then @key 
                  else Abs(pkey) end
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
 select * 
 from mytable
 where ((@key=0 AND pkey>=0) OR (@key<>0 AND pkey = @key))
```

Comment: Your method worked fine. The other sql was just more readable.

Comment: Glad to help :) Take a look at this blog though, http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2003/11/14/513.aspx He recommends avoiding `CASE` in `where` clause.

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you . by using case statement you can apply dynamic filter ..

```
select *   
from mytable  
where  1 = case 
             when @key=0 then case when pkey>=0 then 1 else 0 end
             else case when pkey = @key then 1 else 0 end
           end
```